# How to debug a NotifydatasetChanged that is not working?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

NotifydatasetChanged it not working. I searched a lot but seems of no help.

```
public class PlaylistTracksAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public PlaylistTracksAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        mContext = context;
        this.songsList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return songsList;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.song_layout, null);
        }
        TextView mtxtSongName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
        TextView mTxtSongAlbumName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
        TextView mTxtSongDuration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_songduration);
        mtxtSongName.setText(songsList.get(position).get("songName"));
        mTxtSongAlbumName.setText(songsList.get(position).get("songArtist"));
        try {
            mTxtSongDuration.setText(getDuration(Long.parseLong(songsList.get(position).get("songDuration"))));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.d("NumberFormatException", "" + e);
        }
        return convertView;
    }



    public static String getDuration(long millis) {
        if (millis < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duration must be greater than zero!");
        }
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
        millis -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(6);
        sb.append(minutes < 10 ? "" + minutes : minutes);
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(seconds < 10 ? "" + seconds : seconds);
        //sb.append(" Secs");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
  case DELETE_ITEM: {
            removeFromPlaylist(this, mSelectedId, playListID);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
```

I am able to delete the desired songs from the playlist but my listview is not updating.

Comment: Make sure the contents of `songsList` in `PlayListTracksAdapter` actually is modified. You are probably either changing the contents of a copy of the list, or you aren't reloading the list after the change has been made and before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Try changing getItemId to return position instead of 0 and getItem to return songsList.get(position) instead of songsList.  If that doesn't work please include your removeFromPlaylist method in the question.

Comment: There were a number of problems on your latest question relating to readability, as well as the expectation that someone would just fix it for. Imagine my frustration when I spend a few minutes repairing it, only to find that it has been deleted once I have nearly finished! Moral of the story: write questions as clear as you can, and ask for assistance rather than expecting someone to do it for you. Refrain from asking for urgency/ASAP etc as well! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are deleting object please delete them from the list which you passed to the adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged ().

Or you can also create adapter object with new modified list and set it to list.

Both will do. Hope it helps.

Comment: seriously you are life saver thanks alot bother thank you.....i was deleting it from the database but not from the list so it wasn't changing.